# What does "anchor in the past" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "anchor in the past" mean in the following passage?

> *Stories are a narrative of events that **anchor the present culture in the past**. Veteran employees tell stories to new employees about past organizational events that serve to illustrate and reinforce the current culture of the organization.*

Taken from: http://study.com/academy/lesson/employee-socialization-maintaining-a-company-culture.html

Comment: This could use a link to the source or at least more context. As it is, think of *in* as *to*, meaning the present culture is linked to the past culture.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Here is the source:  
http://study.com/academy/lesson/employee-socialization-maintaining-a-company-culture.html

Comment: It is better to include the link in the question :-) and also to throw in one or two surrounding sentences. I hope that this is what you were aiming for (if not you can always roll back the edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A physical *anchor* is a heavy weight tied to a rope meant to keep a ship in place, so the ship does not float away.  It can also be generalized to mean something that keeps something else connected, in such a fashion that it is not wanting to "let go".

So the sentence is saying that stories keep the present culture connected to the past culture, implying that it supports the development and essence of the current culture.

Comment: Stor**i**es, I believe :-) +1 for a clear explanation

Comment: I just wanted to add that I've heard this type of usage many times, but it's always seemed a bit ambiguous.  It may be nice verbiage but it is not very concise or descriptive IMHO.  Just another common metaphor: sometimes used well, but generally abused.